# Spring Boot - REST and SOAP combination

Tags: java, spring, rest, soap, spring-boot

I have a need to write an application that works as follows:

1. I can POST a soap document to /a/abc, the usual SOAP way.
2. I can GET /a/abc, and return a 200/Ok. This is simply a test to see if the method exists.

What is the proper way to do this? I have not seen a way to do a GET in the SOAP context. I've tried creating both REST and SOAP beans as follows:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean WsRegistrationBean(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/a/*");
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean RsRegistrationBean(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/a/*");
}
```

However this doesn't work, the SOAP bean seems to win. If I comment out the soap bean, my REST controller is correctly handling the GET request, but if I leave the SOAP bean in there, I get a "405 / Method Not Allowed".

Can these coexist and have the GET handled by the Rest controller, and the POST handled the SOAP way? Or is there another way?

Comment: You are mapping both Servlets to the same url context of /a. I'd suggest you use different paths for them cause sooner or later you'll run into an issue when POSTing.

Comment: Unfortunately my requirement is to get and post to the same url context. I have to use get to test the Iuri context exist, and if it does then I can talk soap to that context.

Comment: Hmm sounds like a really strange requirement? Is the Get just to check if the endpoint exists? Then maybe implement a Dummy op which you also call as Soap service.

Comment: It's unfortunately a design in the Microsoft MDM discovery server specification, as used by Windows 8.1 and WIndows 10. It's  somewhat of an ugly design which mixes up REST and SOAP concepts. Yes, it's meant to check if the server is there with the correct API, before starting transacting. I am okay with the url-rewriting solution in my answer below for now, although I wish I knew how to do it in the application.  As for your suggestion, I couldn't figure out how to do a SOAP GET (whatever that means), it seems to be refused with a 405.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't manage to find an answer to this, but I do have a workaround:

1. Move the rest controller to a different url context (e.g. /b/abc).
2. Put nginx in front of the application
3. Have nginx rewrite the requests to "GET /a/abc", into "GET /b/abc".

So far this seems to work ok for my needs. There are probably multiple ways of doing this, but I couldn't figure it out with the built-in tomcat, and the nginx approach keeps the redirection external to the application.